# Find a specific pattern in a string using regex

Tags: python, json, regex

```
RT @Complex: 'Atlanta' Season 2 director: "If the first season is College Dropout, this one is Late Registration." 

@pastorjnelson Pastor JN, I have spoken to you before.  But, lol, you didnt know who I was.  Or maybe, I didnt know2026
```

Suppose I have two strings shown above. I want to fetch a specific string pattern from a given line @____ using Python regex. How can I do that?
The expected output should be @Complex for the first string and @pastorjnelson for the second string.

Comment: `re.findall(r'@\S+', text)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = """RT @Complex: 'Atlanta' Season 2 director: "If the first season is College Dropout, this one is Late Registration." 
@pastorjnelson Pastor JN, I have spoken to you before.  But, lol, you didnt know who I was.  Or maybe, I didnt know2026 
"""

print re.findall("@\w+", s)
```

**Output:**

```
['@Complex', '@pastorjnelson']
```

Comment: When I do this it gives me like [u'@Complex']  and [u'@pastorjnelson'] in return. I want just text like @Complex

Comment: the snippet is returning you a list. You can access your required element using index 0. EX:  print re.findall("@\w+", s)[0]

Comment: I have two different string. So I think it won't return list in my case.

Answer (score 0):

`@.+?\W` matches both of the above examples.

`@` is the literal @

`.+?` searches for an arbitrary sequence of at least one non-line break characters

`\W` matches a non-alphanumeric character.

Comment: IT says invalid expression for @.*+\W

Comment: Ah yes, you're quite right - this is what happens when I make changes without testing them! Should have fixed it now